# How to turn off password check

Tags: google-chrome

The newer version of chrome shows a password check when it thinks the password has been leaked:

[image]

We have a demo server, where we want the users to also see the login process: thus we show the demo login user credentials directly on the login-screen: e.g. `demo@example.com` / `demo`.
So in this case, the check is useless because we explicitly want the credentials to be public.
The warning message is in this case bad, because users may think it's a problem of our site/webpage.

Is there a way to turn this off (e.g. via some html-tag,..)?
It would be best, if it could be turned off only for the `demo@example.com` user, so that the check can still work for other users.

Comment: This won't be a helpful comment in the sense of helping you solve your problem. But logging into stackoverflow on my phone. I got this same message. I assume google will tweak this in some sort of way or somehow allow the users to toggle this on or off in some sense.